# Allowed duplicate record if data not exist in different column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

I have 2 column name `location_id` and `district_id`. `location_id` record can be duplicated if existing `location_id` and `district_id` record does not match. The table below will explain it.

[image]

Notice the duplicate record of `location_id` and `district_id`. This table has valid data.

How can I `UPDATE` with mysql while preventing duplicate. With below syntax, my table can be updated even if `B008` and `01010244` already exist.

```
    UPDATE 
    `location_id`, district_id 
    SET
      `location_id` = 'B008',
      `district_id ` = 0101031504
    WHERE `id` = 5
```

My second query above will update even though existing record with similar data already existed.

Please assist and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem *structurally*, by adding a Composite `Unique` constraint on the `location_id` and `district_id` together. This will block any new DML operations trying to create duplicate rows for the combination.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name 
ADD UNIQUE `unique_location_district` (`location_id`, `district_id`)
```